# the ajax return values are not used in the function

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

index.php

```
$(function () {
  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'sort.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
        $("#hoverdemo").dotHover(response, { img: '665.png' });
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

sort.php

```
$array=[{ x: 28100, y: 48500, text: 'A' },{ x: 28100, y: 48500, text:'A' }];
echo $array;
```

response is running when copying and pasting the value of $ array from the other page to the split :S

Comment: Does `dotHover` expect the first argument to be a string?  Because that's what you are giving it.  Also, what's the problem?

Comment: $("#hoverdemo").dotHover([{ x: 28100, y: 48500, text: 'A' },{ x: 28100, y: 48500, text: 'A' }], { img: '665.png' });   code work

Comment: You are missing my point.  Web requests, typically, only send data as text.  If you want the response to be something else, such as an actual array object in this case, you have to parse the text returned and turn it into an actual array.  It is not being transferred to you as an array.  It is a string.

Comment: hmm.  how can i help you?

Comment: What do you mean, "help me"?  I'm trying to help you understand why the variable is a string, and not an array.  Also @charlietfl is going into the meat of the issue below.

Answer (score 3):

You need to send json not echo the array itself.

Change  `echo $array;` to `echo json_encode($array);`

Also syntax for php array should be :

```
$array = [
  ['x' => 28100, 'y' => 48500, 'text' => 'A'],
  ['x' => 28100, 'y' => 48500, 'text' => 'A']
];

// OR
$array = array(
   array('x' => 28100, 'y' => 48500, 'text' => 'A'),
   array('x' => 28100, 'y' => 48500, 'text' => 'A')
);
```

Then add `dataType:'json'` to the `$.ajax` options so the json string will be parsed to a javascript array inside the success callback

Comment: charlietfl thank you for your answer. do I have to parse the return value?

Comment: Not if you set dataType ... jQuery will parse it internally

Comment: success: function (response) {
        $("#hoverdemo").dotHover(response, { img: '665.png' });

not work. I guess I'm doing it wrong

Answer (score -1):

```
      $(function () {
  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'sort.php',
        dataType:'json',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
        $("#hoverdemo").dotHover(response, { img: '665.png' });
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

sort php

```
 <?php
```

$array=[{ x: 28100, y: 48500, text: 'A' },{ x: 28100, y: 48500, text: 'A' }];

echo json_encode($array);
?>

not work :(

Comment: You need to set Content-Type to application/json because if you don't jQuery will not convert it to JSON.